# Changing frame of many UIObjects with same code

Tags: ios

I wanted to apply this same effect to 10 UIobjects (most of them are UIImageViews) at the same time. This is the animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f
                 animations:^{

woodenBackground1.frame = CGRectMake(self.woodenBackground1.frame.origin.x - 900,self.woodenBackground1.frame.origin.y, self.woodenBackground1.frame.size.width, self.woodenBackground1.frame.size.height);

woodenBackground.frame = CGRectMake(self.woodenBackground1.frame.origin.x - 900,self.woodenBackground2.frame.origin.y, self.woodenBackground1.frame.size.width, self.woodenBackground2.frame.size.height);
```

.....

Is there a way to do it? How can I repeat it for that many objects instead of repeating the code itself?

Comment: Those lines of code aren't the same. Just because they "look" the same doesn't mean that there are ways to optimise the writing of them. Maybe you should be looking at how your views are laid out (if they're really doing exactly the same thing why are they all separate views?). If they're not then sometimes you just have to accept that you'll have to write 10 similar lines of code. Trying to be clever may only hurt maintainability in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put all of the views inside a container UIView and apply the animations to the container view if they're all moving the same amount.

Answer (score 1):

Take one View and add all the 10 Objects in that view.whenever you want to change the frames you can use this code.

```
for(UIView *view in someview)
    {
        view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x - 900,self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    }
```

If all are present in self.view then give tag value to the objects and based on that tag values you can change the frames

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to place all your views in an array.  Then create a category for a NSArray where you define a method called makeObjectsPerformSelector: withStruct:

This would allow you to execute it like below all in one line.

```
[viewArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setFrame:) withStruct:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x - 900,self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```